# How do I define my app home screen group name?

Tags: ios, xcode

I'd like to define a default folder name on home screen for my apps (which are Ad Hoc distributed), such as the default apps when they are dragged to ("Productivity", "Utilities", "Games", "Navigation"):

[image: Default predefined folder name]

Instead of default name "Folder":

[image: Default folder name]

How can I achieve this?

Edit:

I tried adding LSApplicationCategoryType to Info.plist, but that doesn't seem to affect anything.

Comment: The feature names the folder according to its contents.

Comment: Default Folder name is probably calculated from first two applications (from which folder is created) using their primary application's category, which You provide when upload app to AppStore. This is just a guess.

Comment: @GuntisTreulands That's also my guess, but I tried setting LSApplicationCategoryType, and that didn't seem to work on Ad Hoc distribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will work only on AppStore versions. I tested with bunch of my Ad-hoc releases and their AppStore releases. - For ad-hoc releases - "Folder" name appears.  For AppStore versions - App, which is moved onto other app - it's category name is used. (In case Ad-hoc is moved onto AppStore app, then AppStore app's category is used).

Anyways, I checked out that `LSApplicationCategoryType`   https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/LaunchServicesKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009250-SW8

Did You use for example for "Education"  - public.app-category.education ?

Either way - it might not even be intended to work on debug/ad-hoc releases as stated in the same page:

> LSApplicationCategoryType (String - OS X) is a string that contains
>   the UTI corresponding to the app’s type. The App Store uses this
>   string to determine the appropriate categorization for the app. Table
>   2 lists the supported UTIs for apps.

...which sounds like, that this value is used by App-Store, to correctly set Applications category, which then is used to categorize applications on springboard.

So I guess, this will work only when App is downloaded from App Store.

Comment: That seems like it. Though it is annoying App Store can set Application category on device correctly but ad hoc distribution can't :(